# Flushing Rake output immediately to Powershell host

Tags: powershell, rake

I have rake task which takes input from user.
I am invoking the rake task from powershell script as below:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production | Out-Host
```

But using the above command line , I have issue where the rake task output is not immediately getting flushed out to the host.
 When ruby script S3 is executed and waiting for user input.
Powershell is also waiting  for user input but does not display the message given at S3, instead it just displays as if executing at script S1.

So both are not in sync and user does not know what to enter?

Comment: Do you actually _need_ to pipe to `Out-Host`? Maybe try adding `STDOUT.flush` at the various points in your ruby scripts where you need the buffer to be cleared

Comment: `& { rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production } | Out-Default ` or `Start-Process rake 'db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production' -NoNewWindow -Wait`